# Xcode 'Capture OpenGL ES frame' responds with 'application not found'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opengl-es

I'm using Mavericks with Xcode 5.0.2 running on iPhone 5s with 7.0.4.

When I click 'Capture an OpenGL ES frame' Xcode shows an alert with 'application not found'.

See for bug report: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5796292978540544

Can anyone reproduce the problem? Any hints to solve this?

Update:
Only occurs with the iPhone 5s, not the iPhone 5.

Comment: I am also having this issue... but on an Mini iPad Retina.

Comment: 2015 - and still the same issue - iPhone 6, iOS 8.3, but just restarting device helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: Restore (not only reset) your iOS device.**

I went to the Apple Tech Talks in Berlin last week and talked to some of the OpenGL engineers. It is not a computer problem and doesn't depend on your installed system or Xcode version.
It only occurs with the A7 devices. Still the engineers are also not 100% sure what is worng.

I tried to reset (contents and settings) my phone which didn't work. Restoring the device completely with iTunes which finally solved the problem.

Comment: we had the same issue and rebooting the device solved the problem. apple engineers should make a better message 'application not found' is really too vague.

Comment: + 1 This is the best route - you do not need to completely restore the device. Just a switch off and on again solved it for me with iPad Air 2.